# Solution to Detonate the Maximum Bomb problem on Leetcode

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

Today I came across the Detonate the Maximum Bomb Problem on Leetcode

https://leetcode.com/problems/detonate-the-maximum-bombs/description/

It goes like this:

> You are given a list of bombs. The range of a bomb is defined as the area where its effect can be felt. This area is in the shape of a circle with the center as the location of the bomb.

> The bombs are represented by a 0-indexed 2D integer array bombs where bombs[i] = [xi, yi, ri]. xi and yi denote the X-coordinate and Y-coordinate of the location of the ith bomb, whereas ri denotes the radius of its range.

> You may choose to detonate a single bomb. When a bomb is detonated, it will detonate all bombs that lie in its range. These bombs will further detonate the bombs that lie in their ranges.

> Given the list of bombs, return the maximum number of bombs that can be detonated if you are allowed to detonate only one bomb.

I made a python program to solve the problem, it goes like this

```
import math

class Solution:
    def maximumDetonation(self, bombs: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        maxDetonations = 0
        for i in bombs:
            detonated = [i]
            undetonated = [bomb for bomb in bombs if bomb != i]
            for bomb in undetonated:
                if Solution.dist(i, bomb) <= i[2]:
                    detonated.append(bomb)
                    undetonated.remove(bomb)
            for bomb in detonated:
                for b in undetonated:
                    if Solution.dist(bomb, b) <= bomb[2]:
                        detonated.append(b)
                        undetonated.remove(b)
            
            if len(bombs) - len(undetonated) > maxDetonations:
                maxDetonations = len(bombs) - len(undetonated)

            print(maxDetonations, detonated)    
        return maxDetonations    

    @staticmethod
    def dist(cod1, cod2):
        return math.sqrt(math.pow(cod1[0] - cod2[0], 2) + math.pow(cod1[1] - cod2[1], 2))
```

The program, iterates over each bomb, and finds the bombs which would detonate from the bomb, and than keeps finding the bombs which would explode from the bombs which exploded. It uses,
"dist" function to find the distance between the bombs and check if any undetonated bomb is present in the affected region to detonate it.

It works for all of the testcases, except one which goes like

> [[634,440,278],[748,509,396],[995,881,251],[704,214,341],[832,972,238],[987,384,156],[378,988,402],[743,557,252],[814,868,196],[131,922,199],[13,398,444],[464,607,241],[426,128,81]]

There are thirteen bombs in this testcase, and according to Leetcode, 12 of them can be exploded with a single detonation, but my program just gives 10 as max possible explosions, can you please help me to find what is the mistake and whiere is my program going wrong. Here is a graph for this test case as a reference

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8fcozrqrl0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not modify a list while iterating over it with a for-loop.

Comment: What can I change to fix that

Comment: Replace both `for ... in undetonated` by `for ... in undetonated[:]` to iterate over a copy of the list. Iterating over `detonated` while appending values should even work here although it isn't a clean solution.